# How to debug in my case

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am new in iOS development. I made a simple iOS app project. The build is successful, but when I run the app on my iphone (It is a registered device), it launches the app with a black screen, and xcode shows me the following thing:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([MyDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

and a message `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT` is shown under `[MyDelegate class]` of above code.

The device log shows me the following:

```
Failed to load bundle from /var/mobile/Applications/C1B10964-7216-2272-BA95-A0CC0C1CA2D0/Documents/core/my.bundle. Reason: (null)
Aug 21 16:03:05 John-iPhone MyApp[254] <Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Exception', reason: 'Could not load code from bundle'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (0x2ebbefd3 0x39435ccf 0x176ed 0x1377d 0x3144a5a7 0x31449efb 0x3144458b 0x313e0709 0x313df871 0x31443cc9 0x33a4caed 0x33a4c6d7 0x2eb89ab7 0x2eb89a53 0x2eb88227 0x2eaf2f4f 0x2eaf2d33 0x31442ef1 0x3143e16d 0x16b49 0x39942ab7)
```

That's all the information I have. I have no clue how to debug with these information. Could someone please guide me on how to solve the app launching problem based on above information I get from xcode?

Comment: please add exception breakpoints to see where it crashes

Comment: It has nothing to do with the code in `int main....` this is just where it will land if you don't catch the exception. You can use what are called exception breakpoints to catch this and see where it is failing. But remember that line doesn't matter it really doesn't have anything to do with that bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an Exception Breakpoint to make the debugger stop before crashing when an error appears:
[image]

Comment: But I need to know which line of code could be the cause, then I put the break point around there, right? My problem is I don't know where to put a break point, because all the information is ambiguous.

Comment: No, you click on "Add Exception Breakpoint like on this screenshot, and the debugger will show you which line is faulty.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the exception breakpoint
http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions

Answer (score 0):

If you click on Xcode gutter (line 15 on example picture), you put a breakpoint who will stop your code.
You can process step by step to find where is the problem
[image]

Comment: But my problem is I don't know where could be the cause of the problem, where should I put the break point

Comment: Xcode is it updated ? (last release version ?)
Have you writes some code or it's the Xcode new project who crashes ?